# Changing Properties values in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

I am trying to load dynamic values from properties file into a Bean Class (Spring MVC project).

I had used following tags to load values.

```
<context:property-placeholder 
        location="file:/home/java/examresults/departments.properties" 
        ignore-unresolvable="true" order="2"/>`
```

But changing the value in properties file after starting the application, it does not reflected at the form.

I am injecting these values into a class using following declaration.

```
<bean id="beanmessage" class="examresults.bean.MessageClass" scope="prototype">

        <property name="imagelocation" value="/home/java/examresults/"/>  
        <property name="boards" value="${boardvalue}"/> 
        <property name="departments" value="${deptvalue}"/>
    </bean>
```

Hence, I am not able to fully utilizing the properties file in my Spring MVC Application.

Comment: Spring does not support dynamic reloading of properties like that. You could reload the application context but that is probably overkill. There are ways to deal wih hot reloading of resources like jrebel, or even jmx/JNDI.

Comment: You should **not** want to change a property file once the application has started. If the values are dynamic, put them in a database, or in a plain file, but do not ask Spring for that.

Comment: Why i would create another table just for changed values? If I am putting values on a external file, then this should be retrieved accordingly. But got the point that I still need to restart the application server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the properties file, the webserver needs to be reloaded to make the changes reflected.

When a webserver start, it will instantiate all the registered bean with the configured properties. So if you made changes to the configuration after the webserver started, the bean doesn't know about the changed configuration, because it's already instantiated in the application context / IoC container.

To make the changes in properties files reflected is done by restarting / reloading the webserver (either tomcat or jetty).